# Regex for a string - length 9, Third character letter and remaining numeric

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am trying to create a RegEx to match a string with the following criterion

- Length 7 or 9
- The first character must be a letter a-z or A-Z if a number of characters are 7. The remaining 6 must be numeric 0-9.

example:

```
a555444
B999999
```

- Third character must be a letter a-z or A-Z if number of characters are 9 The remaining 8 must be numeric 0-9

example:

```
12B456789
16K456745
```

My regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}$
```

This is what I have so far and its handling only first scenario. Please help me in constructing a regex to handle this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an alternation:

```
^([A-Za-z][0-9]{6}|[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z][0-9]{6})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iheVnN/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(` - start of a grouping construct (you may add `?:` after `(` to make it non-capturing) that will match either...

  - `[A-Za-z][0-9]{6}` - an ASCII letter and then 6 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z][0-9]{6}` - 2 digits, 1 letter, 6 digits
- `)` - end of the grouping construct
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I think this will match to a string with 7 char on the first word and 8 chars on the next which it should not as per the problem description. https://regex101.com/r/1hYXGW/1

Comment: @printfmyname I think the first "requirement" pertains to both scenarios. So, it matches both correctly as per the problem description.

Comment: @Wikor Stribizew Its working as expected. Thanks for clear explanation

Comment: My objection was overthrown by judge Vijay.. I misunderstood the question then.

Comment: @printfmyname :Thanks. The requirement should handle both scenarios in question. Quick question ! can you pleas help me in tweaking below email regex to accept only 3 digit domain names such as .com,.gov,. [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?

Comment: @VijayD Replace the trailing `[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?` part with `[a-z]{3}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex like that:

```
^([0-9]{2})?[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}$
```

`?` shows that `[0-9]{2}` group is optional.

So if you have a string with length 7, this group doesn't exist. If you have a string with length 9 this group exists.